# Persistent Session in Nodejs using MySql

Tags: mysql, session, express

new to nodejs. this might be a silly/easy question

I have an Express App and i am using mysql for persistent sessions. (using express-mysql-session to do that).

Here's code snippet from app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var SessionStore = require('express-mysql-session');
var app = express();

app.use(session({
  store: new SessionStore({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'test',
    password: 'test',
    database: 'test'
  }),
  secret: 'secret_key',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));
```

routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.post('/login', wrap(function* (req, res) {
        var email = req.body.email;
        var password = req.body.password;
        var response = yield new AccountController().login(email, password);

        if (response.status === 'success') {
            req.session.account = {
                accountId: response.accountId,
                accountStatus: response.accountStatus
            };
            req.session.save(function(err) {
                if (err) console.log('error in saving session: ' + err);
            });

        }
    }
}));
```

The get and set method of express-mysql-session are called everytime a request is sent.
I wanted to know how can i set my custom data into the persistent session store without using any other library like passport.
and also how to read the store too.

Comment: Isn't that explained [here](https://github.com/expressjs/session#reqsession)?

Comment: yes, but the thing is that its not saving the session data in mysql even after calling the req.session.save.
is there something else that needs to be done to do that?

Comment: If `.set()` is being called I would assume that the session data is being saved. Is it saving a new session id by any chance?

Comment: yes, a new session id is being generated and .set() is being called, but its not reflecting in the session store i.e mysql db table sessions.

Comment: Can you show how you are using the sessions in a route handler? Also, is the database completely empty? And does every request get a new session id (which it shouldn't)?

Comment: no everytime i start the app, only then a new session id is generated, otherwise the same sid is used.
I have updated the post itself with routes.js code